# Android Start calendar intent with start and end time

Tags: java, android

I have an app with an agenda with list of times and date. When user clicks one of these events, the Calendar intent should start so should bring up the Calendar with the time, date and reminder preset. However when I load up the intent, the start time is just the current time and the end time is an hour ahead. Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong. Here is example of hard coded calendar with date and time set up I am testing with

```
Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance();
startDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, 8);
startDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2012);
startDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 5);
startDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);


// Set the calendar
Calendar endDate = Calendar.getInstance();
endDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, 8);
endDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2012);
endDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 5);
endDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
endDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.putExtra("calendar_id", 1);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("beginTime", startDate.getTime());
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
intent.putExtra("allDay", false);
intent.putExtra("endTime", endDate.getTime());
intent.putExtra("title", "A Test Event from android app");
intent.putExtra("description", "Your consulting date and time");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching. I found this method. Bit annoying but it works

```
java.sql.Timestamp tsStart = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(year+ "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour + ":"+ minute + ":00");
java.sql.Timestamp tsStart = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(year+ "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour2+ ":"+ minute2+ ":00");

long startTime = tsStart.getTime();
long endTime = tsEnd.getTime();
```

I was just hoping I could use the Calendar method to set date and time, although guess doesn't really make a difference. Also heads up to people using this method, make sure your year month day hour etc fields match up the the timestamp format. In my application, when I clicked on an agenda it would take the Date and time string of that event and then I was splitting it up like this

```
String array[] = tvSessionTime.getText().toString().split(" ");
String array2[] = array[0].split(":");
int iHour = Integer.parseInt(array2[0])
int sMinute = Integer.parseInt(array2[0])
String array3[] = tvSessionDate.getText().toString().split(" ");
```

And if you had a time like 07.05 and you parse the hour, the hour will come back as 7 and the minute would come back as 5. And the format is yyyy-hh-mm. So this was bringing back an error as it didnt match the date format. Just a heads up!