# Changing date and time on calendar

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

I'm trying to create and app where I can click on a button and add an event to the primary calendar on the phone. I was wondering what the format was to input the start and end time. Here is my code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("beginTime", startTime);
intent.putExtra("allDay", false);
intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
intent.putExtra("endTime", endTime);
intent.putExtra("title", title);
intent.putExtra("location", location);
startActivity(intent);
```

right now startTime = 7:00 PM and endTime = 9:00PM

Comment: Is this what you need?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687628/android-start-calendar-intent-with-start-and-end-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the android docs about calendar providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intent-insert) begin and end time is in milliseconds since epoch:

> [...] extra fields to pre-populate the form with the time of the event. The values for these times must be in UTC milliseconds from the epoch.

---

Additional notes: Why are you using an `ACTION_EDIT` intent? To insert events, use `ACTION_INSERT`. If you with to change an existing event, you need to specify its id, you can find an example in the [same android doc article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intent-edit).

I'd encurage you to use the android constants such as `CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME`, so you're safe from mistyping stuff.